# Update query to reset table field per month basis

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `service_tracker`. The table contains 6 fields but the most relevant to my question below is `cycle_start` and `last_used`. Currently I am able to determine the following things about a `service`: the times it has been used (`usage_count`) by `user` within 1 month (`last_used`,`cycle_start`). First query adds 1 to the `usage_count` as long as it is not older then 1 month. Second query clears and sets the `usage_count = 1` if older than 1 month. Queries work great, however, would it possible to perform this on the basis of the twelve months of the year? Clear and set to 1 the `usage_count` once April, May, June etc. is over?

Queries:

```
UPDATE service_tracker
  SET usage_count = usage_count + 1,
  last_used = CURDATE()
WHERE service_tracker = 'cloudstorage' AND `user` = 'test2' AND last_used >= date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month);
UPDATE service_tracker
  SET usage_count = 1,
  last_used = '0000-00-00',
  cycle_start = CURDATE()
WHERE service_tracker = 'cloudstorage' AND `user` = 'test2' AND cycle_start < date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month);
```

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_tracker` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cycle_start` date NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `usage_count` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `last_used` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `service_tracker` (`id`, `service`, `cycle_start`, `user`, `usage_count`, `last_used`) VALUES
    (1, 'webserver', '2015-04-24', 'test1', 13, '2015-04-24'),
    (2, 'cloudstorage', '2015-04-16', 'test2', 390, '2015-04-30'),
    (3, 'web-traffic-tracker', '2015-04-16', 'test3', 1916, '2015-04-30'),
    (4, 'remote-it-help', '2015-04-16', 'test4', 91, '2015-04-16');
```

Comment: Why not just log usage?? User,date_used

Comment: You can use the mysql scheduler to perform tasks on given (repeating) periods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mysql scheduler to run queries at specific (and repeating) times.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT reset_usage_count
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2015-05-01 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 -- your query to reset the usage_count
END$$    
DELIMITER ;
```

This one would start the query at midnight, on the first of every month.  You will need to make sure the global variable `event_scheduler` is set to on.  You can check that it is running by executing `show proceslist`, and looking for `User: event_scheduler`

Comment: Great, how would i select the database for the scheduler? For example database named 'masstracker'?

Comment: @MaryCoding `use masstracker` then create the schedule. alternatively, you can always explicitly specify the database in a query by specifying `database.tablename` instead of just `tablename`