# MySQL Trigger to execute for every day of the week

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, triggers

I want to trigger my database to subtract 15% from a different group of values on every day of the week.

For example, if COLUMN_1 = 5 for several rows, then I want the value in COLUMN_2 for those rows to be changed if today is Monday. On Tuesday, COLUMN_2 should change for rows where COLUMN_1 = 6, etc.

But as far as I can tell, triggers only activate on INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE events; how can I write a trigger to activate as soon as a new day starts?

I think the MySQL WEEKDAY() function will help, but I'm not sure where to insert it in the syntax of the trigger to accomplish what I want.

Possibly, I'm misunderstanding this, and what I want to accomplish is done in with PHP. I'm not sure

Comment: Checkout mysql event scheduler

Comment: ^^ try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960870/update-query-to-reset-table-field-per-month-basis/29960962#29960962.  that one is per month but it should give you the idea